# Arduino and 2 MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet

I want to turn on 2 bulbs using 2 MOSFETs. The problem is that they both turn on when it should turn up just one light.

Code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13,1);  
  digitalWrite(13,0);
}
```

See circuit below:

[image]

Comment: What sort of MOSFETs are they? (part numbers)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a delay into your loop. In your code pin 13 will toggle very rapidly, much too fast to see it. For example:

```
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);  
  delay (1000);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  delay (1000);
}
```

---

It doesn't look wired correctly. For an N-channel MOSFET the Source should go to ground, like this:

[image: Low-side driver]

Answer (score 0):

The following circuit diagram works perfectly.

[image: Mosfet circuit]

Answer (score -1):

i prefer you to use relay to control any ac appliance with arduino it very much safe...[image]

Just follow this circuit diagram and use 5v relay in your project it will always work fine.....

Comment: I fail to see how this can help. OP is not attempting to control an A.C. appliance, the diagram clearly shows that they are D.C. Also, the OP has no button in their circuit, so that is completely superfluous.